# check if the all values of array are different

Tags: c#, arrays, distinct-values

I have a one-dimensional array like this:

```
int[] values = new int[5] { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 };
```

Now I do this to check if all values are different:

```
bool all_values_are_different()
{
   for(int i = 0; i < values.Length - 1; i++)
   {
      search = values[i];

      for(int j = i + 1; j < 5; i++)
      {
         if(search == values[i])
            return false;
      } 
   }

   return true;
}
```

Is there any method available in C# to check that all values are different in the array?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

There are several ways:

```
// 1
values.Distinct().Count() == values.Length;

// 2
new HashSet<int>(values).Count == values.Length;

// 3.1
!values.Any(x => values.Count(y => x == y) > 1);


// 3.2
values.All(x => values.Count(y => x == y) == 1);
```

If the result of any of these expressions is *false*, that means your array has duplicates, otherwise all elements are unique.

Answer (score 1):

You can *sort the array if possible*. The data will be sorted **in-place** without creating a new array like other methods, thus should be faster, especially when you want the data to be sorted later (like for binary searching or displaying). Besides it's only O(n log n) instead of O(n<sup>2</sup>)

```
Array.Sort(values);
for (int i = 0; i < values.Length - 1; i++)
{
    if (values[i] == values[i + 1])
        return false;
}
return true;
```

You can also copy to a new sorted array when you want both the sorted and original array, or simply because you don't want to modify the input. I think it's still faster than O(n<sup>2</sup>) methods or some solutions that use a set, especially for large inputs

---

An alternate solution if the original array is to be preserved

```
var valueList = new HashSet<int>();
foreach (var v in values)
{
    if (valueList.Contains(v)
        return false;
    else
        valueList.Add(v);
}
return true;
```

This is faster than Selman Genç's second solution since it doesn't populate the whole set and returns early if possible

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
 var duplicates = arrayToCheck
    .GroupBy(s => s)
    .Where(g => g.Count() > 1)
    .Select(g => g.Key);


   return (duplicates.Count() > 0);
```

P.S

```
return  arraylist.Distinct().Count() == arraylist.Length;
```